# Setting the height of an object to match a floated object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, height

So I'm making myself a website and I have hit a brick wall. I would like to know if it is possible to use JavaScript to get the height of a floated object, and set the height of another object with this floated object's height. Basically the second object would ideally be the same height as the floated object, which just so happens to be a video with an id attribute. I would like to know if this is even possible? And if so, how to do it?

So far this is the code I have:

Two examples of the HTML blocks:

```
<div class="vidFloat" id="vidFloat">
    <div class="floatL"><video id="vid" src="../vid/videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls></video></div>
    <h2>this video...</h2><p>hi there</p>
</div>

<div class="vidFloat" id="vidFloat">
    <div class="floatR"><video id="vid" src="../vid/videoname.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls></video></div>
    <h2>this video...</h2><p>hi there</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var vidRef = document.getElementById('vid');
var mHeight = vidHeight.offsetHeight;
var contentHeight = document.getElementById('vidFloat').style.height;

if (contentHeight!=mHeight){
  contentHeight.style.maxHeight = mHeight;
}
```

CSS:

```
.vidFloat{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
.floatL {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.floatL video{
  width: 100%;
}
.floatR {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
.floatR video{
  width: 100%;
}
/*
The following are IDs used in javascript, and then media queries
*/
#vidFloat{}
#vid{}
```

Comment: Is it possible but I see some mistakes in your code : vidHeight (l.2) seems to be undefined.
You just have to get the .height() (check js doc, you could need outerHeight for exemple) of a div and assign a new height to another one : secondDiv.style.height = firstDivHeight

Comment: Which is the element you want to get the height? vidFloat? or the inside div with class floatL of floatR?

Comment: The element to set the height is vid, which is a video html5 element, I want to set the height of vidFloat using vids height. VidFloat has also got an ID called vidfloat in which I am setting the max height...

Comment: why use javascript, if you are wanting equal height blocks in pairs, you can use `display:flex`: https://jsfiddle.net/03pj60wk/

Comment: Paul, do yo think something like this would be better then:                      var vidRef = document.getElementById('vid');
var mHeight = vidRef.height();
var contentHeight = document.getElementById('vidFloat').style.height;

if (contentHeight!=mHeight){
  contentHeight.style.maxHeight = mHeight;
}

Comment: In my above fiddle, you can see each video box keeps the height of the one next to it - just add as many video boxes within the container div as you want, sorry I had a typo on the wrap: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03pj60wk/3/

Comment: Also Pete, what I am trying to achieve is a parent object set to the same height as one of its children, so I don't think display flex would work... correct me if I'm wrong though, I haven't really used display:flex; for anything.

Comment: are you not just wanting the `vidFloat` divs to be the same height?

Comment: No that part is fine, the height of the videos is set automatically and all I set on those is the width. this way the videos keep their aspect ratio. I'm just trying to achieve something similar to whats in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CompTutor/L1jf1L9r/